# Smart Map - Sorting for closest location in PHP

Tags: elementcriteriamodel, plugin-elementapi, plugin-smartmap

I want to sort entries with a Smart Map address field for closest location. I know how it should be done in a template:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.myAddress(params).order('distance').find() %}
```

Only, I would like to do so in my business logic and not in my template. I tried something like this.

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->section = 'houses';
$criteria->myAddress->target = '90210';
$criteria->order = 'myAddress.distance';
```

However, this does not work.

Is this possible? I tried related options but can't seem to get anything to work. Can I also do this with the Element API plugin to return the results as JSON?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're very close!

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->myFieldHandle = array(
    'target' => 90210,
    'range' => 100
);
$criteria->order = 'distance';

$results = $criteria->find();
```

I've never actually tested it with the Element API plugin, but in theory it should work just fine.

In response to this question, I've added [instructions for PHP](https://plugins.doublesecretagency.com/smart-map/sorting-entries-by-closest-locations/#php-in-a-separate-plugin-or-module) to the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Just figured out how to actually use the Smart Map plugin with the Element API plugin:

```
...
'endpoints' => [
    'entries.json' => [
        'criteria' => [
            'section' => 'sectionHandle',
            'address' => array(
                'target' => '50.25641910,6.10379780',
                'range' => 20
            )
        ],
    ]
]
...
```